# Recommended best practice for distributed eviction for EhCache?

Tags: java, caching, jvm, ehcache, distributed-computing

I have multiple nodes running a JVM Spring app using ehcache for local caching.

I wanted to find out from the community what the best practice would be to do cache eviction for a specific element properly across this cluster of nodes. For example, if on Node 1, we realized that we need to evict item of id 123( or update using CachePut ), we will need to evict (or CachePut ) across all the other nodes too.

My current way of doing it is Node 1 informing all the other nodes using Redis Pub/Sub to force all nodes to evict item of id 123.

Is this a good method or there is a better practice in the industry?

I was reading and it seems like doing ehcache replication across nodes might be one other alternative?

I am curious to hear what others say about this.

Thanks
IS

Comment: This is too close to a request for a discussion, which is explicitly off-topic on SO.

Comment: Sorry, where should it go then? It has been a while since I have posted on SO

Answer (score 1):

Distributed caching frameworks are providing ways to synchronize. Ehcache, when using a Terracotta cluster, will make sure all near caching is not stale when a modification is done from one of the client.

Bottomline, a good caching frameworks should take care of this for you.